# Where to place .gitignore file(s) under docker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, docker, docker-compose

I'm working on my first docker-compose.yml that includes a rails app.

How should I handle .gitignore files?

In the main directory I have:

- docker-compose.yml
- README.md
- *plus a folder for each non-image container*

I've generated a Rails app in the relevant container directory.
This includes the standard generated .gitignore file.

Should I *move .gitignore to the main directory and keep all the ignores in one place*
OR
*leave it where it is and keep the ignores at the container directory level*.

Are there any gotchas I've not seen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is generally easier to manage ignore elements in one place.
Both for:

- `.gitignore`
- [.dockerignore](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) (used before the docker CLI sends the context to the docker daemon, when doing an `ADD` or `COPY` in the Dockerfile)

Comment: Thanks, Von. Thanks for the pointer to .dockerignore too, not come across that file before. Forewarned is forearmed.

Comment: This guy's reputation just overpassed StackOverflow counting structure. 1005K instead of 1M.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a **.gitignore** in every single directory of your project.

However, the best practice is to have one single **.gitignore** file on the project root directory, and place all files that you want to ignore